# In case if BGP connected to two peers then how Graceful restart capability advertised in open message

Tags: bgp

As per RFC 4724 "A BGP speaker MUST NOT include more than one instance of the Graceful Restart Capability in the capability advertisement [BGP-CAP].  If
   more than one instance of the Graceful Restart Capability is carried
   in the capability advertisement, the receiver of the advertisement
   MUST ignore all but the last instance of the Graceful Restart
   Capability."

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Each peer has a separate connection, so there is one capability advertisement for each peer.